# Help with Amplifier Circuit

Tags: amplifier, ltspice

How can I analyze this differential amplifier circuit? I need to find the differential gain, the common mode gain and the CMRR (common mode rejection ratio). And is the schematic okay? The amplitude in the voltage sources is 5V and the frequency is 1kHz.[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are Q2 and Q3 flipped? They will sort-of work connected like that, but not very well. Both your power supplies are also flipped.

Comment: The sim circuit drawn is a train wreck. Try putting this right and simulating to find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple differential pair.

From a differential standpoint the collector of QB is a differential ground, so the differential gain will be gm1*RC or (IC/Vt)*Rc, where IC = IQB/2.  You can figure out IQB2 by analyzing the current mirror.

From a common-mode standpoint the collector of QB is an open circuit, so unless you have some mismatch in there you will have infinite CMRR.  (since your diff-mode gain is finite, and your common-mode gain is zero).  To see this imagine that V1 and V2 move together (i.e. in common-mode.  Then the collector of QB will track them as well (the dc level of the collector will be (V1 - VBE1).  Therefore the small-signal VBE of Q1 and Q2 won't change, so no gain.

Your schematic is funky.  Q2 and Q5 are connected upside down.  Also, VCC needs to be more positive than VEE.  You have them backwards.  Try VEE = -5 and VCC = 5 and see what you get.

Comment: Technically, the common-mode gain will be zero not because \$Q_B\$'s \$r_o\$ is infinite, but because \$V_{OUT}\$ is defined to be differential (i.e., even for finite \$r_o\$, \$A_{CM}\$ is still infinite because \$V_{OUT1}=V_{OUT2}\$). You're on the right track, Q1-Q2 mismatch will change this situation...

Comment: Correction, \$A_{CM}\$ is still *zero* despite finite \$r_o\$, but mismatches in Q1-Q2 *and* RC-RC1 change the situation...

Comment: Who says that Vout is differential? Why should we assume that the emitter current source is IDEAL? The quality of this source alsao determines the common-mode gain.

Comment: @LvW The schematic indicates two outputs Vout1 and Vout2, they are not independent therefore they are differential.  If you choose to look at one of the two, it is still a differential output, you're just throwing away the benefits (and half the gain).  And I don't assume the emitter current source is IDEAL.  The collector of the emitter current source is a common-mode ground so ro of Q4 doesn't play into it.

Comment: crgrace, if the long-tailed pair is (ideal) symmetric a differential output ALWAYS gives Acom=0 - even for a poor current source (resistor R) in the common leg. More than that, I dont think that in the given circuit the collector of Q4 provides a common-mode ground (for a finite diff. r.out for Q4). The common mode gain (for one unsymmetric output node) is Acom=-gmRc/(1+2gmrout)

Comment: @LvW Are you talking about the first or the second schematic?  I'm not sure we disagree.  If the diff pair is perfectly matched, Acm = 0 (since the emitters are at a virtual ground).  If there is any mismatch in Q1, Q2, RC, or RC2 then Acm != 0.  For example see slides 7 and 8 of: http://www.ece.sunysb.edu/~oe/Leon/ESE372S13/Lecture22.pdf

Comment: In principle, I see no difference between both circuits. As I have mentioned: Acm=0 for differential output ONLY. Emitters are at virtual ground for an IDEAL current source only. Otherwise my formula for Acm applies (unsymmetric case, finite r,out). Slides 7 and 8 show an IDEAL current source!. Read the last line in slide 8.

Comment: OK, I think we totally agree.  One of the hardest things in electronics is communications, right?  I'm 100% in agreement that if the circuit is single-ended the CM gain is not zero.  I should point out in slide 8 the current source is not ideal, it has finite output resistance  Slide 7 has an ideal current source but that doesn't matter for the differential case.  Your formula is for a single-ended case and I completely agree with it.